# Creating an animated clock

Tags: android, widget, clock, alarm

I want to create a clock widget like the example. But I don't if i would start with java or if this would be possible with an xml? I am just looking for a good place to start. Is there maybe some couple of functions or places i could look at as an example? I don't see how you can set up the minute and hour hands to work around that center point.

basically can i do this all xml? or do I use java and can I get a starting point for either or?

Thank you so much.

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnYI.jpg).

Comment: Your question is phrased in a way that makes it seem like you are asking us to design and write this program for you. Could you rephrase your post into a specific question? Also it would be nice if you were to mention the things you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it pure XML, as XML is just a way to organize info
so you could do it in java, as for the start, i unfortunately don't know how to code in java,
but can give some advice:

First, you will need to have the Java applet get current time from somewhere, whether online or the windows clock, next you will probably have to use a java graphics library to draw the clock and animate it. You may need to map the time to a certain graphic, or frame for the clock, finally set up a loop to update constantly and check the time. Good luck!